# PHP/Regex: Get content between Stars but not if there's a leading backslash

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get everything between two stars - except of they have a leading backslash.

So for example:

```
*hello* world
```

should return "hello", but

```
*hello \* world*
```

should return "hello * world"

I tried the following regex:

```
/(?<!\\)\*(.+?)(?<!\\)\*/s
```

which works perfect on http://regex101.com/ but php returns:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 21

What am I doing wrong?

--

EDIT 1:
Here's my PHP-Code for that:

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/(?<!\\)\*(.+?)(?<!\\)\*/s', '<strong>$1</strong>', '*hello world*'));
```

Comment: Could it be that you're not escaping the backslashes?

Comment: I even don't have any in my string I give. I always get errors

Comment: Please paste your call to `preg_replace` in your question. The problem is almost certainly something to do with escaping as @Biffen says. Possibly you're using `"` quotes instead of `'` quotes?

Comment: @MaxiNet I meant in the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not escaping the backslashes correctly which results in escaping the `)` character.

To match a `\` in PHP you need 4 backslashes

```
/(?<!\\\\)\*(.+?)(?<!\\\\)\*/s
```

> It must be done like this because every backslash in a C-like string
>   must be escaped by a backslash. That would give us a regular
>   expression with 2 backslashes, as you might have assumed at first.
>   However, each backslash in a regular expression must be escaped by a
>   backslash, too. This is the reason that we end up with 4 backslashes.

Or use a character class with 2 backslashes

```
/(?<![\\])\*(.+?)(?<![\\])\*/s
```

> A literal backslash can also be matched using preg_match() by using a
>   character class instead. Backslashes are not escaped when they appear
>   within character classes in regular expressions. Therefore (“[\]“)
>   would match a literal backslash. The backslash must still be escaped
>   once by another backslash because it is still a C-like string.

**Edit** Found [this article](http://www.developwebsites.net/match-backslash-preg_match-php/) which explains why this is necessary. Also, added explanations.

Comment: Not that it makes much difference, but maybe a little more readable than "\\\\" is `\\{2}`

Comment: It depends how you write the string, for example if you use the heredoc or nowdoc syntax, you only need two backslashes.

Comment: Actually in a single-quoted pattern the escape-level is different and only 3 backslashes are needed to match a literal backslash (which is not in a character class) [var_dump('a\\\b'==="a\\\\b");](https://eval.in/187756), but 4 works too :) Using 3 before a `'` would not work / escape the `'`.

Comment: @Jonny5: it works too with double quoted strings: `var_dump("a\\\b"==="a\\\\b");`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Depends: [var_dump("a\\\t"==="a\\\\t");](https://eval.in/187825), [var_dump('a\\\t'==="a\\\\t");](https://eval.in/187829)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\*(.*?(?<!\\))\*
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xE0sY9/1)**

[image]